# Meteor HTTP request structuring

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

I am playing around with some API in meteor and am trying to use the HTTP package to access it. The example they give formats the request as a Curl command like this :

```
curl -X POST https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search/ -d '{"fields":["name","menu_items","location","categories","description"],"menu_item_queries":[{"price":{"$ge":15},"name":"steak"}],"venue_queries":[{"location":{"locality":"San Francisco"}}],"api_key":"YOUR_API_KEY"}'
```

How do I convert this into an HTTP.call()? Do I use the data argument I see listed in the docs? Params? Content? The variations I have tried so far haven't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the equivalent. It's a bit prettier in javascript.

Server side code:

```
var result = HTTP.post("https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search", {
    data: {
        "fields": ["name", "menu_items", "location", "categories", "description"],
        "menu_item_queries": [{
            "price": {
                "$ge": 15
            },
            "name": "steak"
        }],
        "venue_queries": [{
            "location": {
                "locality": "San Francisco"
            }
        }],
        "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY"
    }
});

console.log(result.data); //
console.log(result.content); //.data is better if the output is in json
```

If you use client-side code, it is not advised due to the API key, you would have to use the callback instead.

Comment: in the future you shouldn't answer questions that don't say what they've tried.  We don't want to be doing people's "homework" for them.

Comment: @xaxxon Seems a bit unfair. Most meteor users are learning. I suspected s/he did try data but passed it along as a string instead of an object. Meteor does better with the object itself.

Comment: that's not just my opinion:  http://stackoverflow.com/tour - Dont't ask about:  Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!) "the variations I've tried so far haven't worked" isn't showing your work.